# Integrate Firebase with my Web app to send notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am kinda stuck with firebase, and any help will be appreciated.
My goal is to whoever opens my page get a notification to allow / block. Whoever allows notifications, I want to send him notifications in the future over https://console.firebase.google.com - Cloud messaging app.

I have achieved something, when I open my web page over https I get notification do I want to allow or not

[image]

After I allow, when I try to send a message over cloud message to all participants of the project I get nothing.

First I set firebase configuration

```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration 
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDX5nRZCEI-wxp7L7TzI3lYQXlFlIZq7Rw",
    authDomain: "braintech-6f3cf.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "braintech-6f3cf",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    appId: "1:747770571255:web:da58976e57ebeb0835a6f2",
    measurementId: "G-73HKECM57P"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config); 
  // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
 function setTokenSentToServer(sent) {
window.localStorage.setItem('sentToServer', sent ? '1' : '0');
}

function sendTokenToServer(currentToken) {
    if (!isTokenSentToServer()) {
      console.log('Sending token to server...');
      // TODO(developer): Send the current token to your server. 
      setTokenSentToServer(true);
    } else {
      console.log('Token already sent to server so won\'t send it again ' +
          'unless it changes');
    }
} 

function isTokenSentToServer() {
    return window.localStorage.getItem('sentToServer') === '1';
  }
function getRegisterToken(){
  // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
// subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
messaging.getToken().then((currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    sendTokenToServer(currentToken);

    console.log(currentToken);
    updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
  } else {
    // Show permission request.
    console.log('No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    // Show permission UI.
    updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  showToken('Error retrieving Instance ID token. ', err);
  setTokenSentToServer(false);
});  
}
function showToken(currentToken) {
    // Show token in console and UI.
    const tokenElement = document.querySelector('#token');
    tokenElement.textContent = currentToken;
  }
```

In console log I get a message that token is sent to server. But when I try to send messages nothing happens.
Also in firebase-messaging-sw.js which is in same folder as index file,

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.3.4/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDX5nRZCEI-wxp7L7TzI3lYQXlFlIZq7Rw",
    authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx",
    appId: "1:747770571255:web:da58976e57ebeb0835a6f2",
    measurementId: "G-73HKECM57P"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(config); 
  // Retrieve Firebase Messaging object.

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages. 
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Not sure what is wrong? Any help would be appreciated